# Can I just reassign list instead of using persistentlist in ZODB

Tags: python, zodb

In [this document](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zdgbook/ZODBPersistentComponents.html), a method of handling mutable list in ZODB is introduced, which is "to use the mutable attribute as though it were immutable" by reassigning the list. I tried to create a simple but rather long inverted index in an OOBTree structure, where the values are lists. Inspired by the above-mentioned method, without using Persistentlist or anything for that matter, I simply replaced "append" with reassigning the list, and it worked just fine, and the resulting database file is ideally small. I checked and apparently there was nothing wrong with the index, but I just can't feel sure about it. Can it really be this easy? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The following is some fragments of code I wrote to create an inverted index with ZODB:

```
#......
root['idx']=OOBTree()
myindex = root['idx']
i=0
#.....
doc = cursor.first()
while doc:
    docdict = {}
    for word in doc.words():
        docdict[word]=docdict.setdefault(word,0)+1
    for (word,freq) in docdict.iteritems():
        i+=1
        if word in myindex:
            myindex[word]= myindex[word]+ [(doc[0],freq)]
            # This seems to work just fine. 
            # This is where I'm confused. Can this really work all right?
        else:
            myindex[word]=[(doc[0],freq)] # This list is not a PersistentList.
        if i % 200000 == 0: transaction.savepoint(True)
    doc =cursor.next()
docs.close()
transaction.commit()
#......
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can really be this easy.

The `Persistent` baseclass overrides the `__setattr__` hook to detect when changes have been made that need to be committed to the database. Changes to mutable attributes, such as a list, do not use the `__setattr__` hook and are thus not detected.

It's easiest to show this with a demo class:

```
>>> class Demo(object):
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...          print 'Setting self.{} to {!r}'.format(name, value)
...          super(Demo, self).__setattr__(name, value)
... 
>>> d = Demo()
>>> d.foo = 'bar'
Setting self.foo to 'bar'
>>> d.foo = 'baz'
Setting self.foo to 'baz'
>>> d.foo
'baz'
>>> d.spam = []
Setting self.spam to []
>>> d.spam.append(42)
>>> d.spam
[42]
```

Note how the `d.spam.append()` call did *not* result in printed output; the `.append()` call works *directly* on the list, not on the parent `Demo()` instance.

Reassignment, on the other hand, *is* detected:

```
>>> d.spam = d.spam
Setting self.spam to [42]
```

Another way to signal to `Persistent` that something changed is by setting the `_p_changed` flag directly:

```
myindex._p_changed = True
```

If you are ever in doubt that your change is being detected, you can also *test* that flag:

```
assert myindex._p_changed, "Oops, no change detected?"
```

An `AssertionError` will be raised if `myindex._p_changed` is `False` (or perhaps `0`); which is only the case if no changes were detected since the beginning of the current transaction.

Comment: Thank you very much. But if this easy method works well, what's the good of PersistentList? The word itself is rather long and takes a lot of space in the database file. Can I understand this as a room for improvement of ZODB?

Comment: @user2871934: What do you mean with *The word itself is rather long*? The goal of `PersistentList` and `PersistentMapping` is to detect changes to mutable types; when using a regular `list` or `dict` changes to those objects are not detected by the parent object.

Comment: @user2871934: Use them only for *smaller* non-persistent data, **or** use subclasses of `Persistent` to create separate records for entries contained in a `PersistentList` or `PersistentMapping`.

Comment: @user2871934: the point of the PersistentList and PersistentMapping types is for detecting insertions and deletions only.  For your case of just re-assigning every time (which works without this hoop to jump through), why not consider storing a tuple, that is much more self-documenting of your intent without requiring much special kung-fu on your part.

Comment: @Martijn: With "the word itself is rather long", I mean the following: if Persistent is used in the inverted index, a PersistentList is created for every indexed word. In the pickled stream, there are as many occurrences of the word "PersistentList" as the words. It is to reduce the size of the database file that I tried the "reassigning" method and the file size was considerably smaller. Anyway, perhaps I took the database file size too seriously.